# Is it bad practice to only use props in child components? Child components without own state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing an application and all the child components that I have developed don't jave their own state. If not, it's the parent container that passes the state through props and the children modify the props through callbacks. I know that it is normal for simple components, but I have made some component a little more complex without state, and I do not know if it is bad practice. I give an example, although it does not make much sense, to see that the child has logic and modifies the props but does not have its own state.

Parent component

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
     this.state = {
      person: {
        name: 'Jonh',
        surname: 'Bold',
        money: 20
      },
      expenses: 0
    }
    this.handleChangePerson = this.handleChangePerson.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeExpenses = this.handleChangeExpenses.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleChangePerson(value){
    this.setState({person: {...this.state.person, ...value }})
  }
  
  handleChangeExpenses(event){
    this.setState({expenses: event.target.value })
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>
        <PersonalInformation person={this.state.person} expenses={this.state.expenses} handleChange={this.handleChangePerson} />
        <h1>Expenses</h1>
        <input type="number" name="expenses" onChange={this.handleChangeExpenses} />
        <h1>Total money: {this.state.person.money} </h1>
      </div>)
  }

};
```

Child component

```
class PersonalInformation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.expenses !== this.props.expenses){
      this.props.handleChange({money: this.props.person.money - this.props.expenses})
    }
  }
  handleChange(){
    let {name, value} = event.target;
    if(name === 'money'){
      value = parseInt(value, 10);
      value = value >= 100 || value < 0 ? 99 : value 
    }
    this.props.handleChange({ [name]: value})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" value={this.props.person.name} onChange={this.handleChange} /></p>
        <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value={this.props.person.surname} onChange={this.handleChange} /></p>
        <p>Money: <input type="number" name="money" value={this.props.person.money} onChange={this.handleChange} /></p>
    </div>)
  }

};
```

Maybe it is not the best example, but what I want to show is whether it is bad practice or not to have slightly complex child components without state that modify the state of the parent.Or it is better to have a component with its own state that does not directly modify the parent.
Thanks!

Comment: It is not bad if you do not overuse it. Read about prop drilling.

Comment: I don't think "overuse" would be the right term here; I'm not sure how to overuse this pattern. But I'd see the danger of spreading coupled logic in too many places/components which are now tightly coupled but due to the spread you loose oversight.Besides that, I'd advocate for splitting (view)model and controller from the view itself. Putting the state and methods in one component and letting another one render it/deal with the UI.

Comment: @EnClave, just one thing: this code here `this.props.handleChange({money: this.props.person.money - this.props.expenses})` this feels completely out of place. imo it would belong in `handleChangeExpenses`

Answer (score 0):

No it is not bad.

And sometimes it is the simplest way of doing.
Another approaches would involve either a Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
or Redux: https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference

Answer (score 0):

No, [props](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) are made to pass the props from the parent component to childs.

The [class components](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-class-components) are essential and it's good to have and working with them, But just try to optimize your code readability and manipulation by learning/using [functionnal components with hooks](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), they are much easier and don't have the confusion with the `this` keyword.